# How to scaffold identity files in Visual Studio 2019 for mac?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-mac

I have included AspNetCore.Identity in my MVC web app project however, the model and view files do not scaffold automatically.  In Visual Studio for Windows the option to scaffold identity is in the context menu via 'Add > New Scaffolded Item'.  Is there a similar scaffolding option in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac?

I have found info on how to scaffold identity files using terminal [here](https://www.giselletavares.com/2019/01/01/how-to-add-the-identity-files-to-your-asp-net-core-project-with-vscode/) however, my question is about if Visual Studio for Mac has this ability in the UI.

Comment: From the latest notes of [Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-for-mac-version-8-4-is-now-available/#scaffolding) we can see, you can only add `New Scaffolding… ` with common entity. It will be added in the near future.

Comment: This is not currently supported. The identity scaffolder had some problems/missing pieces in Visual Studio for Mac so it was removed. The plan is for it be included in the future - but I do not have a specific release where this will happen.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few solutions:

**(1)** trick: Use Visual Studio on Windows, then scaffolding. Then copy to macOS computer. It's easy way.

**(2)** On macOS computer,  Install tool

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

then generate scaffoloding files

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h
```

Reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli#scaffold-identity-into-an-empty-project

Answer (score 0):

From Scratch.

```sh
dotnet new webapp --output "WebApp1" --name "WebApp1" --auth Individual
cd WebApp1
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity
```

Delete these:

**Areas/Identity/Data**
**Areas/Identity/IdentityHostingStartup.cs**

Not Requiring email Confirmation
In **`Startup.cs`**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            }
        ).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
}
```